# image texture not showing in final render but does in 3d view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, uv-image-editor

So i've modelled a bottle with a label and cap, i am using an image texture on the label which works fine in the render but the one on the cap shows in the 3d view (in live render mode), but not in the final render (as in when i click the "render" button). It just shows the colour of the cap. anyone know why this is? will include pics.[image]
not enough rep to add multiple images so link to imgur: [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTmgE.jpg)

EDIT: thanks for replies, added pictures of settings, let me know if you need anything else.
EDIT2: tried re uploading the image file, renaming it etc, still not showing in final render.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more information like screenshots of mesh settings, modifiers, UV mapping, material and texture options. It's impossible to tell with the available info

Comment: Also check if the texture is still available to Blender where you left it in the same location with the same name. Check modifiers for different settings between viewport and render, and material settings.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the cap label image got moved from the original location. (meaning, the image was on your desktop and moved into a folder for example)

It still shows up in the viewport because it put a "thumbnail" or quick load version of it but it is not accessing the original file.

I would reload the original file again and it should work.